# onclick="USER._like('161', this);"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've seen sites where instead of form buttons, they use links like that

```
onclick="USER._like('161', this);"
```

And when I click on it, it dynamically inserts the data into the database.

What is this called? And are there any tutorials around here?

Thanks.

Comment: Anything programmatic like this within a web page is most likely a scripting language, almost certainly javascript. What it does depends on how the function is written but it is most likely Ajax if the page does not reload when clicked.

Comment: This is called _Javascript_.

Comment: Have you tried Googling "html onclick"?

Answer (score 4):

That is a javascript event handler. Presumablly the function `USER.like` ( or to be exact the method `like` on the object `USER`) makes an ajax call and sends the value `161` to the server which is then somehow recorded.

That said its much better to do it in an unobtrusive manner, meaning that you would not write function call into an html attribute but rather attach an even handler pragmatically from javascript... using assuming this html:

```
<a class="like-button" href="#" data-id="161">Like</a>
```

Achieving the same thing in an unobtrusive manner with jquery would look like:

```
$(function (){
   $('.like-button').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         USER.like($(this).attr('data-id'), this);
   });
});
```

Comment: USER is most likely a JS object. Also agree with attaching handlers as this allows to decouple view and logic.

Comment: Yes, `USER` is an object... most likely adhering to the Module pattern. But thats not terribly relevant here.

Comment: How do I process the data? I don't see a link to the php file in the code.

Comment: That all happens inside `USER.like`... Basically you just send an ajax request with the proper parameters to your php script.